# Accepting a Request URL is incorrect?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, request

This started happening over the last weekend that FB notification page is no longer embedding the `[app_id]` in the acceptance URL and throwing a 404 when clicked on the "request" link on this page:

(Sent Today)
http://apps.facebook.com/224695104250620/?request_ids=161817803905540&ref=notif

Notice that how it is different than what we used to get earlier (and the working version):

(Sent September 21)
http://apps.facebook.com/piratesapp/?request_ids=10150329048068535&ref=notif

I've gone back and re-checked Facebook documentation on "Requests Dialog":

```
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
```

and found that it clearly states the working version:

```
http://apps.facebook.com/[app_name]/?request_ids=[request_ids]
```

None of the app settings changed on our part and all on a sudden, the strange # started showing up in place of `[app_name]`. We've verified that it's not app_id as it doesn't match with any of our registered apps. The behavior appears to be the same across apps, apps across different Facebook developer accounts and so on.

Is this a bug? Should I file a bug with Facebook? I wanted to check with the experts here before logging a bug.

Appreciate a prompt response on this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like this is a bug:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/209695662429264